# Float equivalence of 1.0E7

Tags: java, floating-point

From an api I getting a float value `1.0E7`, but what exactly api trying to send is `9999999.99`. As it is using `float` data-type to send the this value, rounding will happen automatically in api's `host` side only, and finally what I am receiving here is `1.0E7`.

Is there any way for me to change `1.0E7` to `9999999.99`

Comment: No. The data is lost in the conversion to float.

Comment: This is the API problem, not yours ... You can't fix this safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the rounding happens in the other side the answer is NO.
if you have access to the code you could try the `strictfp` to ensure floating point portability.